# How can I determine if the system is shutting down/restarting or if the user logged off from a WinForms app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, wndproc

How can know what action user have performed ie a shutdown ,restart,stand by, lock or log off. I have used the below code to check it but i want to identify each of the case and perform a action accordingly.please suggest some method to know these details in windows form application

```
 private static int WM_QUERYENDSESSION = 0x11;
    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(m.Msg.ToString() + " Endsession: this is a logoff, shutdown, or reboot");
            systemShutdown = true;
        }
        // If this is WM_QUERYENDSESSION, the closing event should be
        // raised in the base WndProc.
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to check the `lParam` value of the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message.**

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376890.aspx) indicates:

> - If the parameter is 0, the system is shutting down or restarting (it is
>     not possible to determine which event
>     is occurring).
> - If the parameter is `ENDSESSION_CLOSEAPP` (`0x00000001`),
>     the application is using a file that
>     must be replaced, the system is being
>     serviced, or system resources are
>     exhausted.
> - If the parameter is `ENDSESSION_CRITICAL` (`0x40000000`),
>     the application is forced to shut
>     down.
> - If the parameter is `ENDSESSION_LOGOFF` (`0x80000000`),
>     then the user is logging off.

Comment: gray:So i will not be able to identify its a shutdown or restart by this method.will check the lparam ,thanks for the information

Comment: @deepu: No, Windows doesn't distinguish between shutdowns and restarts. Such a distinction isn't made in the method proposed by Fun Mun Pieng, either. Your only options are given by the [`SessionEndReasons` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionendreasons.aspx) as "Logoff" and "SystemShutdown". You don't get any more information going that route than you do handling `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`.

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main()
{
    Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndingEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnding);
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}

static void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndingEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

There could a few other events in `SystemEvents` that you may be interested in.